# Should dateTime elements include time zone information in SOAP messages?

Tags: soap

I've been searching for a definitive answer to this, and [the XML schema data types document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) seems to suggest that timezones are accepted, yet I found at least one implementation which does not properly convert time zones ( NUSOAP ).

To make sure that the problem is not at my end, I'd like to know if a format such as `2009-11-05T11:53:22+02:00` is indeed valid and should be parsed with timezone information, i.e. as `2009-11-05T13:53:22`.

Comment: I added a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following sentences from the w3c schema documentation:

> "Local" or untimezoned times are
>   presumed to be the time in the
>   timezone of some unspecified locality
>   as prescribed by the appropriate legal
>   authority;

and

> When a timezone is added to a UTC
>   dateTime, the result is the date and
>   time "in that timezone".

it does not sound like there is a *definitive answer* to this. I would assume that it is the usual ambiguity: Both versions are principally valid, and the question of what version to use depends on the configuration/behavior/expectations of the system one is interfacing with.

And even *if* there where a definitive answer, I would definitely not rely on it, but rather expect that every other web service and library had its own way of dealing with this :/

Comment: I wonder what has the default timezone to do with a *legal authority*. If I publish a SOAP web-service specifying a default timezone for unzoned `dateTime` values, do I thereby become *an appropriate legal authority*?

Comment: Do I correctly understand you that a conforming reciver is not required to accept both timezoned and untimezoned versions of `dateTime`, letting it balk with something like: *Wrong date format: an explicit timezone is required*?

Answer (score 2):

You converted the timezone incorrectly.

```
2009-11-05T11:53:22+02:00
```

is equivalent to

```
2009-11-05T09:53:22Z
```

Is that what NUSOAP did?

Comment: Sorry, I gave a bad example. The nusoap issue is the following: I send e.g. `2015-10-29T12:59:14Z` which corresponds to a timestamp of `1446116354` , but with when parsing with `mci_iso8601_to_timestamp` I get a timestamp of `1446123554`, which is exactly my time zone's offset from UTC. I'm simply trying to find out if it's me or nusoap.

Comment: `mci_iso8601_to_timestamp` is giving you the correct answer.  `2015-10-29T12:59:14Z` is `1446123554`.  The `Z` at the end means UTC.  If you want to specify your own timezone, you have to give it `2015-10-29T12:59:14+02:00`, which is equivalent to `2015-10-29T10:59:14Z`, which is `1446116354`.