# Calendar issue in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to retrieve the time value (05:58:41.000) from web service which is of data type as `java.util.calendar` and resending the same back to service.
While resending back, I was wondering there was an extra Z(timezone text) was appending like below.
(05:58:41.000Z)

Does this the expected behavior of calendar? Is there any way can we trim the timezone text(Z)?

Your help on this is really appreciated.

My code is not so complex which is very straight forward.

MY POJO class is:

```
Class A {

    private java.util.Calendar time;

    public void setTime(Calendar theTime) {
        time = theTime;
    }

    public Calendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

The mapping code looks like below

```
class Mapping {
    //Invoke a service A and assign the mapping
    A.setTime(serviceResponse.getTime());  
    // from service getting value as 05:58:41.000

    //Invoke the service B by resending the time value as such
    request.setTime(A.getTime()); 
    // While resending back value in the request shows as 05:58:41.000Z
}
```

Comment: try sending it as String

Comment: The design will not permitto send it as string

Comment: tell us how do you print the values / where do you see them.

Comment: This depends on the webservice framework that you're using in your application. SOAP timestamps might or might not have timezone included. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642636/should-datetime-elements-include-time-zone-information-in-soap-messages for some discussion od that.

Comment: Is there any reason why do you wan't that removed? It seems to be a legal part of a SOAP timestamp. The 'Z' indicates the date you're sending back is in the UTC timezone. Does that match the timezone of the Calendar object that you're working with? If yes, then things are fine and you do not need to change anything. Otherwise, just adjust the timezone settings in your `Calendar` instance (that will result in different timezone added to your SOAP message, however that'll be still legal).

Answer (score 0):

In your `request.setTime(A.getTime());` take a local variable make required changes on the data and the set it to `request.setTime(localVariable);`

Comment: No Hopes and there won't be any difference

Comment: I have asked you use it by trimming via a local variable as this is expected calendar behavior

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is expected behavior of Calendar. Your service should be able to consume it without removing the trailing Z

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick response. Let me take this issue further with service